# Vector and ArrayDeque classes

Tags: java, arrays, class, vector

What is the diffirence between Vector and ArrayDeque classes? I read about the ArrayDeque class yesterday, while I have used Vector class before.

Answer (score 9):

The basics are:

`Vector` implements `java.util.List`, which defines containers that allow index-based access to elements. It also implements `interface RandomAccess`, which indicates to the user that the underlying representation allows fast (typically `O(1)`) access to elements.

`ArrayDeque` implements `java.util.Deque`, which defines a container that supports fast element adding and removal from the beginning and end of the container.

Major differences:

- `Vector` supports adding elements into the middle of the container, using the overloaded versions of `List.add(int index, E element)` or `List.addAll(int index, Collection<? extends E> c)`.
- `Vector` supports removing elements from the middle of the container, using the `remove` method.
- `Vector`'s `set` and `setElementAt` methods allow you to do an in-place element swap (replace one object in the `Vector` with another one, an `O(1)` operation).
- `add`ing to the end of a `Vector` is amortized constant time. Adding to the beginning or middle of the vector is a linear time operation (`O(n)`).
- `ArrayDeque` has amortized constant time (`O(1)`) adding/deletion of elements at both the front and back of the container.
- `ArrayDeque` does not allow you to specifically remove an element at a certain position in the container. The various `remove`, `removeFirst`, and `removeLast` methods of the class allow you a slightly more limited element removal.
- `ArrayDeque` comes with methods for using the class like a queue (`peek`, `poll`, `add`, `addFirst`) and like a stack (`offer`, `push`, `pop`, `peekLast`, `addLast`), or like both (hence why it is a [Double-Ended Queue](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_ended_queue)).
- `ArrayDeque` has no support for adding elements into the middle of the deque.
- `Vector` has special `ListIterator`s which allows you to get an iterator that starts at a specific location in the container, and also support adding, removing, and setting elements. `ArrayDeque`'s iterators do not support those extra methods.
- `Vector` is a synchronized container, meaning that it already contains code to perform synchronization/locking for multithreaded environments. For `ArrayDeque`, you have to provide your own synchronization code if you're doing multithreaded access to the container. Note that `ArrayList` is an unsynchronized counterpart to `Vector`.

Answer (score 4):

Few differences:

- Vector implements `List` interface, whereas ArrayDeque implements `Queue` interface. These are different interfaces, providing different set of operations: Vector is your vanilla container, whereas `*Queue` is oriented more towards multi-threaded applications (producer/consumer pattern), since it has methods such as `poll`, `offer` etc;
- Vector thread-safe (it has built-in synchronization), ArrayDeque isn't thread-safe;
- Vector included in JDK since version 1.0, ArrayDeque since version 1.6.

Answer (score 0):

According to Oracle documentation Vector and Stack are legacy classes and you should use Arraylist and ArrayDeque instead.
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/implementations/index.html
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html says "(This class is roughly equivalent to Vector, except that it is unsynchronized.)"